# Connections to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, connection

Possibly a dummy question, but I can't figure it out. It's a concept question.
I have a web platform where users store a lot of things with around 500 simultaneous connections.
In term of performance / security, what is the best approach :

- Connect the user to the DB each time I need to grab data from it (every time he goes to another page BTW) and close the connection after I grabbed them ?
  Or
- Connect the user ONCE to the DB at login, keep the link to the DB (like in $_SESSION) and kill the connection at logout ?
  Or
- At login, grab almost everything from the user table, its profiles one and all the other ones, put them in $_SESSION and only connect to DB when update/insert are needed ?

The connection itself is time consuming that's why I'm looking for the best approach.
But on the other hand, I've always heard "always close your database connection as soon as possible"

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If `$_SESSION` is a reference to PHP, you cannot store resources in PHP sessions.

Comment: That's right ;-). Forgot this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it depends heavily on your specific use case and your server setup. The only way to know for sure, is to try out the different solutions and profile your code.

Usually when you profile your first chosen solution, you'll get hints at what's causing the delays and what is the biggest contributor to waiting/processing time. That way you'll be able to take a better guess at the next (and improved) solution.

Generally it's a good approach to evaluate lazily and then cache as much as possible. For web applications, non-relational databases like Memcached or Redis to name a few, are sort of de-facto standard (at least in my experience).

If you keep your database connections open, you should be aware that you can only run as many concurrent queries as your DB is set up to handle. Closing the connection as soon as possible keeps DB concurrency down.
If the connection establishing introduces a lot of latency, maybe you should consider grabbing all relevant data once in a while and cache them. The only way to know for sure is to profile your application.

*Update:*

> Thanks for your reply. I'll profile this to see what could be better.
>   I'll have a look on MemCached. I wanted to see this later, but I guess
>   that will be the right time. – fperr

I was put off by MemCached at first too, but it isn't complex at all. It works as a (hash)map/dictionary and people usually just save session data on the MemCached instance and index it by the session ID or something similar.

Good luck with your project :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll profile this to see what could be better. I'll have a look on MemCached. I wanted to see this later, but I guess that will be the right time.

Comment: @fperr Are you familiar with web profiling/benchmarking tools? I personally use `ab` - the Apache Benchmark, a lot.